# Laravel Uploaded video is saved in directory with file name instead of in root folder

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, file-upload

my application contains a media upload feature where users can upload images and videos. I have no trouble saving the images, but I'm running into a problem when saving video. Images get resized using `intervention/image`, but video's do not. When I try to save a video, a new folder is created with the hashname of the file + the extension, and the video is saved in there, also as the hashname + the extension. An example of this would be as follows:

`myproject/storage/app/public/media/{id}/b8e79fb3a719afc566f3cbe0ca47e47b.mp4/b8e79fb3a719afc566f3cbe0ca47e47b.mp4`

It should be:

`myproject/storage/app/public/media/{id}/b8e79fb3a719afc566f3cbe0ca47e47b.mp4`

Here is my code for saving the media:

```
protected function saveMedia(UploadedFile $media, int $mediaId)
{


    $mimeType = $media->getMimeType();
    $mediaType = explode('/', $mimeType)[0];

    $path = $media->hashName('custom_slide_media/'.$mediaId);
    if ($mediaType == 'video')
    {
        Storage::disk('public')->put($path, $media);
    }
    else
    {

        $disk = Storage::disk('public');
        $disk->put($path, $this->formatImage($media));
    }

    return Storage::disk('public')->url($path);
}

protected function formatImage($file)
{
    return (string) $this->imageManager->make($file->path())
        ->fit(900)->encode();
}
```

Can anyone tell what's going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the $mediaID from this line

```
    $path = $media->hashName('custom_slide_media/'.$mediaId);
```

and make it

```
    $path = $media->hashName('custom_slide_media/');
```